# Running docker container via crontab does not work

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, cron

I'm trying to schedule docker which run jenkins slave to automatically restart everytime that desktop reboots.

1. *Checking scheduling tasks with crontab using simple script*

   for i in `seq 1 10000`;do touch $i.stam && sleep 1;done

And add it to autorestart with crontab -e

`@reboot /root/script.sh`

**Works as expected - the script starts right after reboot**

2. *Checking manually the docker_run command*

the docker_run.sh script runs the command

`docker run -it -u jenkins:jenkins -v /home/jenkins/.ssh/:/home/jenkins/.ssh/ -v /root/docker-jnlp-slave/.aws/:/home/jenkins/.aws/ jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest`

**works as expected - when running the entire docker run command and when saving it as docker_run.sh script**

3. So great - let's copy to crontab the docker run*

   `@reboot /root/docker-jnlp-slave/docker_run.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

**but than, nothing happens**

Comment: Have you tried to add "--restart always" on your docker command ? check https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: You need to 1) format your code correctly (there are formating aids on the edit page). 2) Provide more information (your docker command, your full sh script, any errors your get from cron in your root system mailbox....). Moreover, this might be considered as [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and is probably better suited for https://superuser.com

Comment: the --restart flag will is for container in case there was some issue with the container but what I need is automatic start of the docker in case that desktop (vm) shut down

Answer (score 0):

"--restart always "resolved it. I didn't understand at the begining how it works. 
Thanks